# How to generate circles every 2 seconds

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio, canvas, geometry

I want to generate circles every 2 seconds, in this case 5 but I can't get it. Instead of creating a circle every 2 seconds, the app wait 10 seconds and draw the 5 circles together. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```
public class Juego extends SurfaceView{

boolean isItOK = false;

Paint paint;
int CantidadDeEsferas = 5;
int radio, alto, ancho;

public Juego(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    paint = new Paint();
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    for (int i=0; i<CantidadDeEsferas; i++) {

        Random r = new Random();
        alto = r.nextInt(canvas.getHeight());
        ancho = r.nextInt(canvas.getWidth());
        radio = r.nextInt(101 - 50) + 50;
        canvas.drawCircle(ancho, alto, radio, paint);
        run();
        isItOK = true;
    }
}

public void run(){
    while (isItOK){
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            isItOK = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

By calling run in onDraw you're pausing the main thread.  Draws don't appear until the main thread returns to the event loop in the framework.  You should NEVER call sleep or other blocking functions on the main thread because of that (basically, your app will appear to freeze).  If you want to do something in 2 seconds, create a Handler and use postDelayed() to send a message to it.  Then have the message's runnable increase the number of circles the view is set to draw, then invalidate the view and post another message for the next 2 seconds.  The view should then draw itself in its onDraw, checking the variable for number of circles to draw.

Answer (score 0):

what about that

```
for (int i=0; i<CantidadDeEsferas; i++) {

    Random r = new Random();
    alto = r.nextInt(canvas.getHeight());
    ancho = r.nextInt(canvas.getWidth());
    radio = r.nextInt(101 - 50) + 50;
    canvas.drawCircle(ancho, alto, radio, paint);
    run();
    while(isItOK);
    isItOk = true;
}
```

Run() method

```
public void run(){
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        isItOK = false;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
 }
```

but i do not like that way you used

NOTE: This class must run by another thread.(in background)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyView extends View {

private Paint paint;
private List<Point> points;
private Handler handler;
private Random random;


public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    handler = new Handler();
    points = new ArrayList<>();
    random = new Random();
    drawCircles();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    for (Point point : points) {
        canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 10, paint);
    }
}

private void drawCircles() {
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                Point point = new Point();
                point.set(random.nextInt(getHeight()), random.nextInt(getWidth()));
                points.add(point);
            }
            invalidate();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
        }
    }, 2000);
}}
```